# Insert data into table using cursor in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am learning pl/sql and I have an exercise to use cursor and procedure or function. The exercise requires to insert data into a table (this will be a support/view table) using a cursor that takes data from other three tables.

Find tables below:

```
CREATE TABLE t_csc (
nr_csc                      NUMBER NOT NULL,
nr_client                   NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
cd_product                  NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
cd_employee                 NUMBER(10),
ds_detail_csc               CLOB,
dt_open_csc                 DATE,
hr_open_csc                 NUMBER(2),
dt_service                  DATE,
hr_service                  NUMBER(2),
nr_time_total_csc           NUMBER(10),
ds_detail_retorn_csc        CLOB,
tp_csc                      CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
st_csc                      CHAR(1),
nr_index_satisfaction       NUMBER(2));


CREATE TABLE t_product (
cd_product         NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
cd_category        NUMBER NOT NULL,
nr_cd_bar_prod     VARCHAR2(50),
ds_product         VARCHAR2(80) NOT NULL,
vl_unitary         NUMBER(8, 2) NOT NULL,
tp_pack            VARCHAR2(15),
st_product         CHAR(1),
vl_perc_profit     NUMBER(8, 2),
ds_complete_prod   VARCHAR2(4000) NOT NULL);


CREATE TABLE t_category_prod (
cd_category  NUMBER NOT NULL,
tp_category  CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
ds_category  VARCHAR2(500) NOT NULL,
dt_start     DATE,
dt_end       DATE,
st_category  CHAR(1) NOT NULL);
```

View table:

```
CREATE TABLE t_ocurrence (
nr_ocurrence_csc             NUMBER NOT NULL,
dt_open_csc                  DATE,
hr_open_csc                  NUMBER(2),
ds_type_classific_csc        VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
ds_index_satisfac_atd_csc    VARCHAR2(30),
cd_category_prod             NUMBER NOT NULL,
nm_type_category_prod        VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
ds_category_prod             VARCHAR2(500) NOT NULL,
cd_product                   NUMBER(10),
ds_product                   VARCHAR2(80) NOT NULL,
tp_pack                      VARCHAR2(15));
```

I tried this code without success:

```
DECLARE
csc_ocurr t_ocurrence%ROWTYPE; -- Declarando uma variável que vai conter T_MC_SGV_OCORRENCIA
CURSOR cur_search IS -- Cria um cursor chamado cur_search do tipo SELECT
    SELECT CSC.nr_CSC, CSC.dt_open_csc, CSC.hr_open_csc, CSC.tp_csc, CSC.nr_index_satisfaction, CATPROD.cd_category,
    CATPROD.tp_category, CATPROD.ds_category, PROD.cd_product, PROD.ds_product, PROD.tp_pack, PROD.vl_unitary, PROD.vl_perc_profit
        FROM t_csc CSC, t_category_prod CATPROD, t_product PROD
        WHERE CATPROD.cd_category = PROD.cd_category AND PROD.cd_product = CSC.cd_product;

BEGIN
OPEN cur_search;
LOOP
    FETCH cur_search INTO csc_ocurr.nr_ocurrence_csc, csc_ocurr.dt_open_csc, csc_ocurr.hr_open_csc, 
    csc_ocurr.ds_type_classific_csc, csc_ocurr.ds_index_satisfac_atd_csc, csc_ocurr.cd_category_prod, csc_ocurr.nm_type_category_prod,
    csc_ocurr.ds_category_prod, csc_ocurr.cd_product, csc_ocurr.ds_product, csc_ocurr.tp_pack; -- 20
    EXIT WHEN cur_search%notfound;
    INSERT INTO t_ocurrence VALUES (csc_ocurr.nr_ocurrence_csc, csc_ocurr.dt_open_csc, csc_ocurr.hr_open_csc, 
    csc_ocurr.ds_type_classific_csc, csc_ocurr.ds_index_satisfac_atd_csc, csc_ocurr.cd_category_prod, csc_ocurr.nm_type_category_prod,
    csc_ocurr.ds_category_prod, csc_ocurr.cd_product, csc_ocurr.ds_product, csc_ocurr.tp_pack);
END LOOP;
CLOSE cur_search;
END;
/
```

Comment: SQL Server uses t-sql, your code is Oracle.

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of "without success"

Comment: Also please note that while this is an assignment to learn cursors, it should not be used in a real application: to insert rows of some SQL result set you should use plain `insert into tab select ...`, that doesn't involve PL/SQL and cursor loop. If some PL/SQL processing is required, for large result sets it would be better to use `fetch ... bulk collect into ...` and then use `forall` statement, which are times faster than row-by-row processing.

Answer (score 0):

If query you wrote returns desired result (I can't tell; statements you posted don't contain any referential integrity constraints, and there's no sample data), then a **simpler** option is to use cursor `FOR` loop because you don't have to declare cursor variable, open the cursor, fetch, take care about exiting the loop and closing the cursor - Oracle does that for you.

Also, note that `INSERT INTO` should always contain all columns you're inserting into. It requires some more typing, but makes it perfectly clear (what is being inserted into which column).

`INSERT INTO` you wrote won't work; if you selected `nr_csc`, you can't insert `nr_ocurrence_csc`, must be `nr_csc` as well. The same goes for bunch of other columns.

Finally, when joining tables, do that *explicitly* - use `JOIN`s. If you name all tables in the `FROM` clause and *join* them in `WHERE`, it'll work (it worked like that *for ages*), but - we don't live in 1990s any more. Leave `WHERE` clause for possible conditions/filters.

Therefore:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2     FOR csc_ocurr
  3        IN (SELECT csc.nr_csc,
  4                   csc.dt_open_csc,
  5                   csc.hr_open_csc,
  6                   csc.tp_csc,
  7                   csc.nr_index_satisfaction,
  8                   catprod.cd_category,
  9                   catprod.tp_category,
 10                   catprod.ds_category,
 11                   prod.cd_product,
 12                   prod.ds_product,
 13                   prod.tp_pack
 14              FROM t_category_prod catprod
 15                   JOIN t_product prod
 16                      ON catprod.cd_category = prod.cd_category
 17                   JOIN t_csc csc ON csc.cd_product = prod.cd_product)
 18     LOOP
 19        INSERT INTO T_OCURRENCE (nr_ocurrence_csc,
 20                                 dt_open_csc,
 21                                 hr_open_csc,
 22                                 ds_type_classific_csc,
 23                                 ds_index_satisfac_atd_csc,
 24                                 cd_category_prod,
 25                                 nm_type_category_prod,
 26                                 ds_category_prod,
 27                                 cd_product,
 28                                 ds_product,
 29                                 tp_pack)
 30             VALUES (csc_ocurr.nr_csc,
 31                     csc_ocurr.dt_open_csc,
 32                     csc_ocurr.hr_open_csc,
 33                     csc_ocurr.tp_csc,
 34                     csc_ocurr.nr_index_satisfaction,
 35                     csc_ocurr.cd_category,
 36                     csc_ocurr.tp_category,
 37                     csc_ocurr.ds_category,
 38                     csc_ocurr.cd_product,
 39                     csc_ocurr.ds_product,
 40                     csc_ocurr.tp_pack);
 41     END LOOP;
 42  END;
 43  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tryed a second time, but now I declared the variables in a procedure. After that I used a cursor to get the data from tables `T_CSC`, `T_PRODUCT` `T_CATEGORY_PROD` and with the cursor opened I `FETCH` the data into the variables declared and with them I use `INSERT INTO` to populate the `T_OCURRENCE` table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_ocurrence AS

v_nr_ocurrence_csc             T_CSC.nr_csc%TYPE,
v_dt_open_csc                  T_CSC.dt_open_csc%TYPE,
v_hr_open_csc                  T_CSC.hr_open_csc%TYPE,
v_ds_type_classific_csc        T_CSC.tp_csc%TYPE,
v_ds_index_satisfac_atd_csc    T_CSC.nr_index_satisfaction%TYPE,
v_cd_category_prod             T_CATEGORY_PROD.cd_category%TYPE,
v_nm_type_category_prod        T_CATEGORY_PROD.tp_category%TYPE,
v_ds_category_prod             T_CATEGORY_PROD.ds_category%TYPE,
v_cd_product                   T_PRODUCT.cd_product%TYPE,
v_ds_product                   T_PRODUCT.ds_product%TYPE,
v_tp_pack                      T_PRODUCT.tp_pack%TYPE;

    CURSOR cur_search IS
    SELECT CSC.nr_CSC, CSC.dt_open_csc, CSC.hr_open_csc, CSC.tp_csc, CSC.nr_index_satisfaction, CATPROD.cd_category,
    CATPROD.tp_category, CATPROD.ds_category, PROD.cd_product, PROD.ds_product, PROD.tp_pack, PROD.vl_unitary, PROD.vl_perc_profit
        FROM t_category_prod CATPROD
            JOIN t_product PROD ON CATPROD.cd_category = PROD.cd_categor
            JOIN t_csc CSC ON CSC.cd_product = PROD.cd_product;

BEGIN
    OPEN cur_search;
    LOOP
        FETCH cur_search INTO v_nr_ocurrence_csc, v_dt_open_csc, v_hr_open_csc, v_ds_type_classific_csc, v_ds_index_satisfac_atd_csc, v_cd_category_prod, v_nm_type_category_prod,
            v_ds_category_prod, v_cd_product, v_ds_product, v_tp_pack;
        EXIT WHEN cur_search%NOTFOUND;

        INSERT INTO T_OCURRENCE VALUES (v_nr_ocurrence_csc, v_dt_open_csc, v_hr_open_csc, v_ds_type_classific_csc, v_ds_index_satisfac_atd_csc, v_cd_category_prod, v_nm_type_category_prod,
            v_ds_category_prod, v_cd_product, v_ds_product, v_tp_pack);
    END LOOP;
END pr_ocurrence;
/

EXECUTE pr_ocurrence();
```